# Java programs using NIO framework

Tags: java, nio

I am doing some research related to Java NIO. I need to find some representative 
applications that are based on this framework. Please feel free to suggest! The more, the merrier!

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/) Networking framework is built on NIO (and is used by many applications to provide high-performance networking).

> Apache MINA is a network application
>   framework which helps users develop
>   high performance and high scalability
>   network applications easily. It
>   provides an abstract · event-driven ·
>   asynchronous API over various
>   transports such as TCP/IP and UDP/IP
>   via Java NIO.
>
> Apache MINA is often called:
>
> - NIO framework · library,
> - client · server framework · library, or
> - a networking · socket library.
>
> However, it's much more than that.
>   Please take a look around the list of
>   the [features](http://mina.apache.org/features.html) that enable rapid network
>   application development, and what
>   people says about MINA. Please grab
>   yourself a download, try our Quick
>   Start Guide, surf our FAQ or start
>   join us on our community

I believe JETTY uses continuations to [support 5000+ HTTP Comet connections](http://cometdaily.com/2008/01/07/20000-reasons-that-comet-scales/) using Servlet 3.0 continuations.

Also you can look at a BlazeDS NIO implementation (basically an opensource LCDS).
http://blogs.webtide.com/athena/entry/asynchronous_blazeds_polling_with_jetty

Comment: The link is Dead! > http://blogs.webtide.com/athena/entry/asynchronous_blazeds_polling_with_jetty

Comment: MINA supports NIO only and not NIO.2.. Netty supports that but their documentation is very bad..

Answer (score 6):

[Netty](https://netty.io/):

> Netty is a NIO client server framework
>   which enables quick and easy
>   development of network applications
>   such as protocol servers and clients.
>   It greatly simplifies and streamlines
>   network programming such as TCP and
>   UDP socket server.

Answer (score 2):

[Grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/), a HTTP connector, makes use of NIO. It's been used in [Sun Glassfish](http://glassfish.dev.java.net) Java EE application server and is available in [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html) Java servletcontainer as well. It not only enables [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (sort of HTTP push idea), but it also scales damn good, it can go up to ~20.000 concurrent HTTP connections on a single thread instead of ~5.000 concurrent HTTP connections on that much threads.

Answer (score 1):

[Rabbit web proxy](http://www.khelekore.org/rabbit/) is using NIO.

But before jumping on the NIO bandwagon, I'd recommend you to read [this](http://paultyma.blogspot.com/2008/03/writing-java-multithreaded-servers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Adobe LCDS runs off Java NIO.

Comment: It seems Adobe LCDS is proprietary, so we don't have access to the code. It would be difficult to study it. But, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I started an open source project on SourceForge called JInSim that uses nio. I'm no longer an active developer on it, but I'm sure that part is still the same. It's a smaller scale library that allows people to write clients for the auto racing simulator Live For Speed.

[JInSim link](http://jinsim.sf.net)

Answer (score 0):

[Jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/), the popular web application server, can use NIO. Check out the different socket connectors. Jetty can also use [continuations](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Continuations) for handling asynchronous web requests.

[Project Voldemort](http://project-voldemort.com/), a distributed key/value store, can also be [configured](http://project-voldemort.com/blog/2009/08/introducing-the-nio-socketserver-implementation/) to use NIO for socket connections and uses parts of the library for reading from it's read-only data store.