# pros and cons of using serialization with java nio versus old socket programming model

Tags: java, server, nio, clients

I want to choose between using old socket programming model (one thread per socket) and new socket programming model which uses java.nio. When I read this article about non blocking socket architecture, I noticed that the architecture is based on the serialization of requests coming from clients.

According to the article, Client applications simultaneously perform requests to the server. The selector collects them, creates the keys, and sends them to the server. So this article confused me, since serialization cannot support scalabity of servers.

If you have 10000 of clients connected to a server, then there should some delay to process all the sub-requests of clients. On the other side,  I read that the only way to scale a server to 1000 of clients is using java.nio.

Here is the article: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/09/04/nio.html?page=2

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862971/java-readobject-with-nio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611152/nio-performance-improvement-compared-to-traditional-io-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671520/java-programs-using-nio-framework

Comment: I don't see any serialization in that article, but I do see several errors. You seem to be using 'Serialization' in some private sense. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So this article confused me, since serialization cannot support scalabity of servers. If you have 10000 of clients connected to a server, then there should some delay to process all the sub-requests of clients.

When there is I/O to process the NIO thread will run at full speed, processing data as fast as it is physically able. The key to keeping the NIO thread performant is to not perform any time-consuming or blocking operations on the thread. You want to handle each piece of incoming data as fast as possible.

Doing this properly means the NIO thread will scale up to the speed of your processor, which these days is considerable.

Yes, at a certain point the NIO thread will consume 100% CPU and won't be able to handle any more I/O. That point is much, much higher than in a traditional blocking I/O architecture though. Not to mention you won't have 10,000+ threads constantly context switching and chewing up huge amounts of resources (stack space, OS task entries, etc.).

If you actually find yourself hitting the limit of what one NIO thread can handle--which is rare--it's easy enough to add additional NIO threads.

Comment: [Architecture of a Highly Scalable NIO-Based Server](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/13/architecture-of-highly-scalable-nio-server.html) provides quite a bit of information about using the Java NIO package with servers.  [Scalable I/O in Java](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/cpjslides/nio.pdf) is a pdf of a slide package that describes socket versus nio approaches.